# It is possible to set a "Version" metadata into a FILE?

Tags: java, android, file, metadata

I need to store in a File a metadata with the version of that File.

For example, the first time i download a File, the server will tell me that the version is 1, so i must store 1 in the metadata "version" of the File. When the server tells me that haves version 2 of the file, i will download and overwrite the file and the metadata with "2".

Is this possible in Java/Android?

Answer (score 1):

No. Just store this information in database, shared preferences or create own `<FILENAME>.meta` file with all the information you need.